# Problem regarding the Wronskian formula

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying from G.Teschl ODE & Dynamical system and I got stucked at problem 3.20, which is:

Find a formula for the Wronskian $W(x,y)=\dot xy-\dot yx$ of the autonomous system $\ddot x + c_{1}\dot x + c_{0}x=0$.

I know I can find the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^{2}+c_{1}\lambda+c_{0}=0$ where the can be calculated and that way try to find explicits solutions. But I don't think that's what is wanted where.

Thanks so much for your answers!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two fundamental solutions of given DE. Then

$x_1''+c_1x_1'+c_0x_1=0$

$x_2''+c_1x_2'+c_0x_2=0$

Multiply first by $x_2$ and second by $x_1$ and then on subtraction, you get

$x_1''x_2-x_2''x_1+c_1(x_1'x_2-x_2'x_1)=0$

$\implies W'=-c_1W$

On integration, $W=k.e^{-\int c_1dx}$, where $k$ is integration constant.